# Why is global array empty after function returned it? (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, return-value, global

I have a function that is recursively opening HTML pages and extracting the articles. After executing the function, the returned array is NULL, but my trace steps between indicate that the array actually contains element. I believe that upon returning the array it gets reset.

**Why is the array containing elements in the function but is NULL after being returned?**

This is the function (simplified):

```
function get_content($id,$page=1){
    global $content; // store content in a global variable so we can use this function recursively

    // If $page > 1 : we are in recursion
    // If $page = 1 : we are just starting
    if ($page==1) {
        $content = array();
    } 

    $html = $this->open($id,$page)) {

    $content = array_merge($content, $this->extract_content($html));

    $count = count($content);
    echo("We now have {$count} articles total.");

    if($this->has_more($html)) {
        $this->get_content($id,$page+1);
    } else {
        $count = count($content);
        echo("Finished. Found {$count} articles total. Returning results.");
        return $content;
    }
}
```

This is how I call the function:

```
$x = new Extractor();
$articles = $x->get_content(1991);
var_export($articles);
```

This function call will output something like:

```
We now have 15 articles total.
We now have 30 articles total.
We now have 41 articles total.
Finished. Found 41 articles total. Returning results.
NULL
```

**Why is the array containing elements in the function but is NULL after being returned?**

Comment: Where is the closing `}` for `$html = $this->open($id,$page)) {`?

Answer (score 3):

Try with `return $this->get_content($id,$page+1);` instead of just calling the function.

If you just call the function without returning, the "initial call" will not return anything and the return value will be lost for subsequent calls of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare $content before first function call if you have not done it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use globals. Especially not if it's just for the sake of recursion.

```
function get_content($id,$page=1, $content = array()){

    $html = $this->open($id,$page));

    $content = array_merge($content, $this->extract_content($html));

    if($this->has_more($html)) {
        return $this->get_content($id,$page+1, $content);
    } else {
        return $content;
    }
}
```

Note that I stripped all debugging output.